# HighCharts/Highstock: How to programmatically draw the mouse line

Tags: highcharts

When you float the mouse over a highstock chart, there is a thin vertical line that follows the mouse, looks like this:

[image]

But when I programmatically trigger the tooltips (the chart is synced with another UI), there is no vertical line:

[image]

It would look nicer if I could get that vertical line in there. Is that possible?

Comment: You are looking for this [option](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair)

Comment: Check for the [Axis.prototype.drawCrosshair()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis.html#drawCrosshair) method - it is used for drawing a crosshair.

Comment: Well, that was enough for me to figure it out, even though I almost gave up. I don't have a mouse event.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment above I got this code working (typescript):

```
     let x = this.chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(milliseconds);
     let y = this.chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(0);
     let e = { chartX: x, chartY: y }; // fake a mouse event that I don't have
     let point = this.chart.series[0].searchPoint(e, true);
     this.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, point);
```

Highstock uses a timestamp on the x-axis, so milliseconds is the timestamp on the x-axis where I want to show the little vertical line (crosshair).